# Can I use a Prepaid Tmn sim from Portugal, outside Portugal (e.g. Spain, Italy)?

Tags: cellphones, italy, spain, roaming, portugal

I bought prepaid Sim cards for 3 months for my husband and my phone so we could contact each other if necessary and so family could contact us in emergency.
In Portugal the phones worked fine.  Now we are in Spain, Seville and when we phone each other calls are redirected to a Tmn number and portuguese message.
We paid 60 euro each and have made 2 1 min calls so should be lots of credit.  Family get same message.  Can anyone help, have been on internet.  Have looked for Tmn office to no avail.
Travelling in Spain and Italy for another 5 weeks.  Do I just write off the 120 euro and go and buy another sim.  Makes me angry.
If so which is best for when we leave Spain in 4 days and go to Italy.
Wont be in big city in Italy where we can buy sim as I believe TIM in Italy is very good to buy to use all over Europe

Comment: Before buying the SIM, did you check with the provider/salesperson that it would work (roam) outside of Portugal? If required, did you activate roaming on the SIMs? Also, 60 euros sounds like a massive amount to spend on a PAYG sim.... Did you buy a lot of minutes or something? (€5-€10 is a much more typical purchase+activation amount)

Comment: May be you better phone TMN: +3519616960000 or check their online page http://tmn.pt (roaming entry in menu available).

Comment: Answer is Yes if you have roaming activated. I am portuguese and live permanent in Sweden. I use a TMN prepaid card. TMN oblidges you to charge the card regularly, so if you don't recharge it for some months the roaming will not work. By re-charging you reactivate the old saldo.